# Read only a segment of text line

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a path only part of which actually exists. I want my script to complete the entire path (the script is for backup purposes).

for example :

```
/home/usr/guy/WDcloud/Linux/pi/backup/usr1
                           ^
                           the actual path up to here exists
```

I can't use `mkdir /home/usr/guy/WDcloud/Linux/pi/backup/usr1` since only part of it exists.

I want a script to check the entire path exists, and if not, complete missing directories and then commence backup for each user.

Comment: Your title is confusing. Could you clarify at all? I think `-p` is what you want as suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is only about `mkdir`, use `mkdir -p /your/partly/existing/path`. From the man page:

> -p     Create any missing intermediate pathname components

But what do you mean by "backup for each use"?

Comment: User not use if I'm not wrong (see revision history). I think you are on the right track indeed, but if the question is unclear, ask for details in a comment